# cmake and Qt boilderplate, cannot initialize a parameter of type 'QMainWindow *' error

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, cmake

im trying to build a boilerplate c++ application using cmake with a main window defined in a .ui file called main_window.xml. I've followed some tutorials and tried to piece together an approach but my knowledge is patchy at best and I've encountered an error that I dont know how to fix.

Does anybody know where im going wrong or if im even barking up the right tree.

Heres the main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "ui_main_window.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     QApplication app(argc, argv);
     QWidget *widget = new QWidget;
     Ui::MainWindow ui;
     ui.setupUi(widget);

     widget->show();
     return app.exec();
 }
```

Here's the CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

PROJECT(test_proj)
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt4 REQUIRED)

# include the current binary output directory as thats where the intermediate Qt fiels will be placed
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

INCLUDE(${QT_USE_FILE})
ADD_DEFINITIONS(${QT_DEFINITIONS})

# set sources of program
# only files that need preprocessgin by Qt need be included
SET(test_proj_SOURCES main.cpp)
SET(test_proj_HEADERS ui_main_window.h)
SET(test_proj_FORMS main_window.ui)

# this block creates .cpp and .h files from the .ui files
QT4_WRAP_CPP(test_proj_HEADERS_MOC ${test_proj_HEADERS})
QT4_WRAP_UI(test_proj_FORMS_HEADERS ${test_proj_FORMS})
# QT4_ADD_RESOURCES(test_proj_RESOURCES_RCC ${test_proj_RESOURCES})


ADD_EXECUTABLE(test_proj ${test_proj_SOURCES} 
                          ${test_proj_HEADERS}
                          ${test_proj_FORMS})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(test_proj ${QT_LIBRARIES})
```

Here's the compile error I get

```
Jonathans-MacBook-Pro:build jonathantopf$ make clean;make
[ 50%] Generating ui_main_window.h
Scanning dependencies of target laser_scan
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/laser_scan.dir/main.cpp.o
/projects/laser_scanner/src/main.cpp:49:17: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'QMainWindow *' with an lvalue of type
      'QWidget *'
     ui.setupUi(widget);
                ^~~~~~
/projects/laser_scanner/build/ui_main_window.h:48:31: note: passing argument to parameter 'MainWindow' here
    void setupUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow)
                              ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/laser_scan.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/laser_scan.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Jonathans-MacBook-Pro:build jonathantopf$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main window is inherited from `QMainWindow`, so you should replace `QWidget` to `QMainWindow` in your main function.

However it's unusual to have a form without a form class. I recommend you to create a class using "Add new - Qt - Designer Form Class" in Qt Creator.